# How do you shadow `gatsby-node.js` of the theme's theme?

Tags: gatsby

I'm using LekoArts' [Minimal Blog theme](https://github.com/LekoArts/gatsby-themes/tree/master/themes/gatsby-theme-minimal-blog). The theme itself uses another theme called [Minimal Blog Core theme](https://github.com/LekoArts/gatsby-themes/tree/master/themes/gatsby-theme-minimal-blog-core).

I'd like to change how pages get created. This code is in the [`gatsby-node.js`](https://github.com/LekoArts/gatsby-themes/blob/master/themes/gatsby-theme-minimal-blog-core/gatsby-node.js) of the core theme, and I'm not sure how to shadow that, or if it's possible.

As far as I could tell, you can only shadow files in the `src` folder of the theme you directly use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gatsby theme shadowing only applies to files in the `src` directory and deeper. You should be able to control page creation from `gatsby-node.js` in the root of your project though. If that file does not already exist, create one. Duplicate the code you want to change from the core themes `gatsby-node.js` and modify it in the `gatsby-node.js` in your project root.